# ScaleY a svg while followed by the below text divs

Tags: css

I need to change the height of a svg on mousewheel/scroll, but while this svg resizes, I need to make the text below follow this `scaleY`. I've tried implementing a `position: relative` but this does not work. How can I do that? Here's a PS of what I try to achieve.

[image]

Here's a PS of what I have now - images and text are just placeholder.

This is my relevant HTML code:

```
    <div className="main_container">
        <div className="main_container_inner">
          <div className="img_container">
            <img src={img_link} />
          </div>
          <div className="text_container">
            <h1>fvdfv</h1>
            <p>fvdfv</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my relevant CSS code:

```
.main_container{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}

body{
  height: 400vh;
}

.main_container .main_container_inner{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 33.33%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main_container img{
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

This is what I have for now:

[image]

As you can see, when I change the `scaleY` value of the image, the text does not adjust to the new height.

Comment: Post your code. HTML, JS, CSS and everything that is relevant. - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: setting display `flex` should work. Put the svg and text under one container and set the container to `flex`.

Comment: @NineTails are you referring to what I added? e.g: `display: flex-inline`? I edited the post

Comment: @cyruslk that comment was prior to the edit. Change `main_container` to `display: flex`.

Comment: @NineTails I've tried and it does not do the tricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the `flex` containers do not have a setted `height` property.

So when you scale an image, it is quite hard to set its container height accordingly, so it "pushes" the other divs below. The image simply overflow its container.

I found a way anyway! Because I sticked (maybe for too long) on that weird challenge.

**It requires a couple calculations.**
I assumed you wish to scale up for the original height of the image to 100% of the viewport height. This assumption may be wrong... I this case, just play with those calculations. You have the example well commented below.

Another thing I noticed is you seem to use React. If so, I guess you should store the img height and its container height in the component state.
   *I'm leaving that challenge to you ;)*

```js
// Get the elements
let main_container = document.querySelector(".main_container")
let imgContainer = document.querySelector(".img_container")
let img = document.querySelector(".img_container img")

// Some global variables to be filled when the image has fully loaded or on window resize
let viewportHeight, scrollHeight, scrollable, currentImgHeight, maxScale

// When the img has loaded...
function imgLoaded(){  
  // Get some dimentions
  viewportHeight = window.innerHeight
  scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight
  scrollable = scrollHeight-viewportHeight

  // Calculate the maxScale for an img height == 100% of the viewport
  currentImgHeight = img.getBoundingClientRect().height
  maxScale = viewportHeight/currentImgHeight

  // Set an initial height to the .img_container - Same as the img.
  imgContainer.style.height = currentImgHeight+"px"
}

// If the image has already fully loaded (cache), else wait for the load event
if(img.complete){
  imgLoaded()
}else{
  img.addEventListener("load", imgLoaded)
}

// On window resize
window.onresize = function(){
  img.style.transform = "scale(1)"
  window.scrollTo(0,0)
  imgLoaded()
}


// Scroll handler
function scrollHandler(){
  
  // update the current img height value
  currentImgHeight = img.getBoundingClientRect().height

  // Calculate a new scale for the img -- The +1 is to avoid a negative value at the bottom of the page
  let newScale = scrollable/(scrollable + 1 - document.documentElement.scrollTop)
  
  // Apply the newScale if less or equal to maxScale
  let scale = (newScale>maxScale)?maxScale:newScale
  img.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale.toFixed(3)})`

  // Adjust the img_container, so it pushes the div below
  imgContainer.style.height = currentImgHeight+"px"
  
  // Just for this demo...
  console.log(imgContainer.style.height,scale.toFixed(3)+"%  ")
}

// Add the event listener
document.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler)
```

```css
/* Just for this demo... Styling the SO console which is in the way! */
.as-console{
  background: transparent !important;
  text-align: right;
}
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 1em !important;
  border-top: 0 !important;
}
.as-console-row-code{
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
}

/* added to your CSS */
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Your css unchanged */
.main_container {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  height: 400vh;
}

.main_container .main_container_inner {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 33.33%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main_container img {
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="main_container_inner">
    <div class="img_container">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" />
    </div>
    <div class="text_container">
      <h1>fvdfv</h1>
      <p>fvdfv</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Run in full screen mode!** or [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/poEWZPG?editors=1111)