# ScaleY a svg while followed by the below text divs: React version

Tags: reactjs

I have asked this question ([ScaleY a svg while followed by the below text divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417839/scaley-a-svg-while-followed-by-the-below-text-divs)) and now I'm trying to format this code to `React.js`. Here's what I have so far. The issue occur when the `window.scroll()` occurs, that sets the image height to 0. I don't get what I am doing wrong here (and I'm still learning react.js) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the relevant `JSX` code:

First, in the `componentDidMount`,`state` and `render`:

```
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loaded: false,
    viewportHeight: null,
    scrollHeight: null,
    scrollable: null,
    currentImgHeight: null,
    maxScale: null
  };
}
  componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollHandler)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main_container">
        <div className="main_container_inner">
          <div className="img_container">
            <img
              onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded}
              src={image_here} />
          </div>
          <div className="text_container">
            <h1>fvdfv</h1>
            <p>fvdfv</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, in the function that is triggered once the image is loaded:

```
  handleImageLoaded = () => {

    this.setState({
      loaded: true,
      viewportHeight: window.innerHeight,
      scrollHeight: document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
      scrollable: this.state.scrollHeight - this.state.viewportHeight
    }, () => {

      let main_container = document.querySelector(".main_container");
      let imgContainer = document.querySelector(".img_container");
      let img = document.querySelector(".img_container img");
      let currentImgHeight = img.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      imgContainer.style.height = currentImgHeight+"px";

      this.setState({
        currentImgHeight
      })
    })
  }
```

Finally, in the`scrollHandler`

```
  scrollHandler = () => {

    let state = this.state;
    if(!state.loaded){
      return;
    }

    let main_container = document.querySelector(".main_container");
    let imgContainer = document.querySelector(".img_container");

    let img = document.querySelector(".img_container img");

    let currentImgHeight = img.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    let newScale = state.scrollable/(state.scrollable + 1 - document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    let scale = (newScale>state.maxScale)?state.maxScale:newScale;
    img.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale.toFixed(3)})`
    imgContainer.style.height = currentImgHeight+"px"
  }
```

The entire source code is [also available here.](https://github.com/cyruslk/very_interesting_paprika/blob/main/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across your question again! It is weird you had no answer yet...

First, I will suggest you to test your React scripts on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) because the "problem" messages are super useful and obvious there. You would have noticed those minor problem right away:

[image]

Here is [your problem reproduced](https://codesandbox.io/s/scale-a-child-image-in-a-flex-element-problem-reproduced-for-so-question-65452865-mx4mi?file=/src/App.js:397-414).

---

Now why the image is getting a zero height on the very first scroll:

You defined a component default state like this:

```
this.state = {
  loaded: false,
  viewportHeight: null,
  scrollHeight: null,
  scrollable: null,
  currentImgHeight: null,
  maxScale: null
};
```

Then on scroll, you do this:

```
let newScale = state.scrollable/(state.scrollable + 1 - document.documentElement.scrollTop);
let scale = (newScale>state.maxScale)?state.maxScale:newScale;
```

That make your `newScale` calculation really being this:

```
let newScale = null/(null + 1 - document.documentElement.scrollTop);    // That is NaN
```

And then, the comparision is this:

```
let scale = (NaN>null)?null:NaN; // The comparision results in false, so scale = NaN
```

I am not sure what happens now with:

```
img.style.transform = `scaleY("NaN")`;
```

How can the browser interprets that for a split second... (lol) But on the second scroll event, that `NaN` become `0`. Certainly because `NaN` is "falsy". I suspect some React magic running behind.

```
console.log( newScale, scale, state.scrollable, document.documentElement.scrollTop );
```

[image]

Anyway, that makes:

```
let newScale = 0/(0 + 1 - document.documentElement.scrollTop);    // That is 0
```

And then:

```
let scale = (0>null)?null:0; // comparision is false again, so scale = 0
```

---

Another "minor" thing is I don't get why you used the `setState` callback in `handleImageLoaded()`...The things done in the callback could have been done upfront.

I played a little with the rest in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/scale-a-child-image-in-a-flex-element-for-so-question-65452865-7deyp?file=/src/App.js)... Check the comments.

Note that I also am learning React... I may just have better bases with JS.
Use the console.log! It exists for a reason. ;)